# What softwares do I have to use to make a 3D spinning globe video to represent data like this video?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, software-recommendation, 3d, animation, adobe-after-effects

I am wanting to create a 3D spinning globe video to represent historical data like in [this video by Business Insider](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=BJ0dZhHccfU), but I don't know what softwares will I have to use to create such a video.

[image]

So I would like to ask that what software do I have to use to make the 3D spinning globe video to represent data like the video above ?

Comment: All comments have been deleted. Comments are for clarifications or suggesting improvements *to the question*; not for answering questions or any other discussion. If you want to discuss the question take it to chat and remember to [Be Nice](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/conduct).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Cinema 4D or Google Earth With After Effects

You could use [Cinema 4D](https://www.maxon.net/en/). I recommend this because it's very powerful, but at the same time, has made a name for itself for being easy to pick up. The learning curve is less than other comparable applications.

Below is an image of a spinning globe I made in **2005** using Cinema 4D. It was very simple to make and only took 30 minutes.

I first created two spheres and sized them appropriately. I then downloaded 3 image maps form the NASA website of the [Earth](https://visibleearth.nasa.gov/view_cat.php?categoryID=1484), Moon and Stars.

I then animated the Earth and moon to spin. I won't talk about the alien spaceship I added as it's not relevant.

Using Cinema 4D you can add multiple animated layers to achieve the effects seen in your video. Alternatively, you can make different versions of the Earth, then overlap them in After Effects using things like layer masks.

After Effects [includes](https://helpx.adobe.com/au/after-effects/using/c4d.html) Cinema 4D, which makes it a seamless process using [Cineware](https://www.maxon.net/en/products/cineware-for-after-effects/).

### LIKE THIS

[image]
[image]

### Using Plugins and Templates

There are many plugins you can use in After Effects to create the animated effects you want as well as templates from places such as [Envato Tuts](https://photography.tutsplus.com/articles/10-easy-animated-infographic-video-templates-for-after-effects--cms-30603) which use After Effect's [Motion Tracking](https://youtu.be/JUCoG7qwYNo) to create the perspective and parallax effects seen in the video you provided.

[image]

[Using AF Only Turial](https://youtu.be/26XGtEeuWyM)

[image]

### Google Earth

Alternatively, you could use [Google Earth](https://www.google.com/earth/). This allows you to make 3D movies of the Earth via predetermined paths. Although you'll have less control, you will find it a breeze to achieve what you want.

Comment: Thanks. After creating the Spinning Earth, is it more difficult to create animated changing territories and moving arrows like in the video above ? https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=BJ0dZhHccfU

Comment: All this is easy in Cinema 4D and After Effects. To achieve the effects that you are after, that is your best bet. There is no easy solution.

Comment: There is an answer below saying that using Blender could be able to create the 3D spinning globe and animated territories and arrows like in the above video, is it correct ? If it was correct, then is Using only Blender quicker and easier than using the combination of Cinema 4D and After Effects ?

Comment: Blender is a free app, so that it's upside, but you'll be limited in what you do when compared to professional packages such as Cinema 4D which is intergraded in to After Effect. I find cinema 4D much easier to work with than Blender also. But It's not cheap. There is a demo version if you want to try it out!

Comment: This should help you choose what is best for the motion grpahics effects you want: https://youtu.be/8BT4YSOjTas

Comment: Thanks for your answer. So I should choose After Effects, right? because there is Cinema 4D automatically included inside After Effects already, right?

Comment: Yes. Correct. However the version of C4D included with AF is C4D Light. But should be all you need :)

Answer (score 1):

Just use Blender. It is one of the best 3D software and its free.

A ton of tutorials, helping comunity, including this one https://blender.stackexchange.com/

You can start using it right now...

Answer (score 0):

Any application (sic) capable of doing 3D Graphics can do this. You should choose an application you know how to use. If you dont know how to use any piece of software then this is generally too broad.

Now if you would ask me to do this I would probably do it in Mathematica, Python (matplotlib), After Effects or Maya if its a one off project. But it really depends on the use case I have and what form the data that i need to animate is in.

But you should probably use Blender if you have no knowledge of the applications I  would use.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. What I really want to do is that I want to animate the changes of the world borders by time. So I will need to draw the borders on the globe and then fill the inner area of the borders with colors to represent territories, and then make them change by time. I only know how to use illustrator, my friend.

Comment: @Zhetdudf thing is making the sphere is easy animating the borders is a bit trickyer.

Comment: Thanks. Is it possible to use Blender to animate borders ?

Comment: @Zhetdudf sure, but borders are harder to animate than something as diffuse as spread of Christianity. For borders you need to morph and have hard edges for Christianity all you need is a gradient map.

Comment: It sounds very complicated. I have no idea what to do.

Comment: I'll need to google more, my friend